# Is there a way to make a winforms usercontrol in a WindowsFormsHost larger?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I have a few usercontrols from an old Windows CE project that I'd like to have in a WPF window, so I've copied the code/design over to the WPF project and dropped the usercontrol into a WindowFormsHost object. It appears to work fine, but the control looks rather small and I'd like to make it bigger. I tried a viewbox but this doesn't actually make it larger (which I kind of expected since it's based around the vector based WPF system). Does anyone know if any way to make a Winforms usercontrol larger in this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the Winforms control(s) use docking or anchoring so they resize with the container there is no easy way to do this.

Perhaps you could change the code of the Winforms controls so they do dock and/or anchor. But even when you do this, fonts will not size along.

Comment: I assumed this was the case, but before I went and mucked with the winform layout/code, I figured I'd asked the SO community. They've proven me wrong plenty of times in the past.